# Crontab unable to run program that calls credentials file

Tags: ubuntu, cron

A newly created crontab job is failing because the program can't read a .json file containing credentials in the same directory. Both files are contained in a `/home/deploy/app/` folder. Crontab executes `/home/deploy/app/app` which needs to read `home/deploy/app/config.json` to execute. The program runs fine a the `deploy` user, but fails when run by crontab.

I am sure this is the reason the program is failing since I directed the crontab job to log its output, and I can see that the program is unable to read the `config.json` file. The `app` has the following permissions `-rwxr-xr-x 1 deploy deploy` and the `config.json` has `-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy`.

The crontab entry is:

```
10 0,6,9,12,15,18 * * * /home/deploy/gocode/bin/BuoyBot > /home/deploy/buoybot.log 2>&1
```

The cron log records the error from the app, which indicates is it unable to load the `config.json` file stored in the same folder as the app.

```
error loading config.json: invalid argument
```

This error does not occur when the program is run manually from within the `/home/deploy/gocode/bin/` folder.

UPDATE: The solution, as suggested below, was to reference the full path of the `config.json` file within the app (`/home/user/app/config.json`), rather than a reference to  the local directory (`config.json`).

Comment: Please show us the output from the log file.

Comment: Added additional information above.

Comment: Work your way through the duplicate above. It will almost certainly help you solve your problem.  If i does not it will help you gather information that will help us help you. That information should be edited into your question.

Comment: I carefully read the above mentioned link, but it does not address the issue. Cron is successfully executing the program, however when it runs the program is not capable of accessing a supporting file in the same directory. More precisely, the command `/home/deploy/gocode/bin/BuoyBot` runs, but the `BuoyBot` program is unable to access the credentials loaded in /home/deploy/gocode/bin/config.json`.

Comment: The app is trying to access to config.json or /full/path/config.json?

Comment: Jose Raul Barreras question solved the issue. The app was referencing the local path. Once I updated the code to include the full path, the file successfully ran in Cron.

Comment: The dupe question now includes a bit on cwd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code my guess is that you are not providing the full path to your data file when you attempt to open it.

Comment: UPDATE: The solution, as suggested by lain, was to reference the full path of the config.json file within the app (/home/user/app/config.json), rather than a reference to the local directory (config.json).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try launching the cron as the user deploy as follows:

```
10 0,6,9,12,15,18 * * * deploy /home/deploy/gocode/bin/BuoyBot > /home/deploy/buoybot.log 2>&1
```

Alternatively you can try as follows also:

```
10 0,6,9,12,15,18 * * * deploy cd /home/deploy/gocode/bin/ &&  ./BuoyBot > /home/deploy/buoybot.log 2>&1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Those are not valid user crontab entries, which is the kind of crontab the OP has indicated (s)he's using.

Comment: This would only work in the /etc/crontab (or similar) file which requires a user name. KIt may not be accessible to the OP. It doesn't work in a user crontab.